# Select con case y decode con distintas columnas

Tags: oracle, plsql

Quiero hacer una consulta con un case y decode en el mismo select con distintas columnas tal que asi:

```
select NOMBRE, 
case when DESDE >= 0000 THEN    decode(DIA,'0','DOM','1','LUN','2','MAR','3','MIER','4','JUE','5','VIE','6','SAB','ALL','TODOS') 
ELSE 'FALSO'as PLAN, 
 from  CALENDARIO j
where SCRIPT like '%prueba%';
```

Pero me da error de missing keyword.
Esto se puede hacer? Hay alguna forma mas optima?
Gracias

Comment: tienes una coma extra después de `PLAN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí se puede hacer, pero te faltó el `END` para cerrar el `CASE` y tienes una coma extra.

```
SELECT NOMBRE, 
CASE WHEN DESDE >= 0000 THEN DECODE(DIA,'0','DOM','1','LUN','2','MAR','3','MIER','4','JUE','5','VIE','6','SAB','ALL','TODOS') 
ELSE 'FALSO' END AS PLAN
 FROM CALENDARIO j
WHERE SCRIPT LIKE '%prueba%';
```